# Getting value of last clicked item from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

*Update #2: Updated scripts.*

## Goal

**a)** User selects a button. The value of the last button clicked + `.current__amount` = `new__amount`

**b)** No running total. Clicking the same button again should deselect it and then subtract that value from `.new__amount` then change the placeholder text using `.html()`

## Problem

Right, now for whatever reason, clicking a button does not add or remove its value from the `.new__amount`.

I've `console.log(buttons[i].value)` and `console.log(buttons[i].class)` and can see that the for loop is printing the class and the value of these six buttons, which represent a bid in a silent auction `$10, 25, 50` and have been stored in an array called `var buttons = []`, like I want.

### scripts.js (Updated)

Almost there. Just need to make it so that only one button can be selected at a time.

```
/*-------------------------------------
STEP ONE: PLACE BID
--------------------------------------*/

$.ajax({
    url: "https://sheetsu.com/apis/4a8eceba",
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json"
}).then(function(spreadsheet) {

    // Print current bid
    var currentBid = spreadsheet.result.pop().Bids;
    $(".current__amount").html("$" +currentBid);

    $('.button__form').on('click', function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if($(this).hasClass('is-selected')) {
            $(this).removeClass('is-selected');
            $(".check--one").css("color", "#ccc");
            currentBid = parseInt(currentBid) - parseInt(value);
        }
        else {
            $(this).addClass('is-selected');
            $(".check--one").css("color", "#ffdc00");
            currentBid = parseInt(currentBid) + parseInt(value);
        }
        $('.total__amount').html("$" + currentBid);
    });
});
```

Comment: You can get the last item in an array this way: `myArray[myArray.length - 1]`... I'm not entirely sure what you're asking though.

Comment: are you just asking how to do `new = current + last clicked`?

Comment: @indubitablee Yes. So that I can change the text of a placeholder on the page to whatever the value of `new` is.

Comment: sorry, its a little hard to follow what you're trying to do with your code with all your selecting/deselecting. what is your final desired functionality? is it to sum up all the selected button values? (so that by clicking once, you select the value and add that value to the total, and by clicking again, you deselect and subtract that value from the total) or is that you are keeping a running total? (in that you press the value 5 button three times and get a total of 15)?

Comment: @Jacques I've tried to provide some more clarifying details, hopefully it makes slightly more sense. Basically, I'm looking to print the value of `.new__amount` which is the combined value `.currentBid` + `theValueoftheLastButtonClicked`

Comment: @indubitablee Yes, I want to sum the selected button value. Yes, on click, the user will select a button, add the button's value to `.current_amount` and print the `.new__amount`. Yes, clicking another button should deselect and subtract that value from `.new__amount`. No running total.

Comment: I've updated the original question to hopefully make things a bit more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this isnt really specific to your question structure but it should get you an idea of how it can work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var totalAmount = 0;
  $('.button__form').on('click', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
      $(this).removeClass('selected');
      totalAmount = parseInt(totalAmount) - parseInt(value);
    }
    else {
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      totalAmount = parseInt(totalAmount) + parseInt(value);
    }    
    $('.total').html(totalAmount);
  });
});
```

```css
.selected {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button__form" value=10>10</button>
<button class="button__form" value=25>25</button>
<button class="button__form" value=50>50</button>
<button class="button__form" value=100>100</button>
<button class="button__form" value=250>250</button>
<button class="button__form" value=500>500</button>
<br/><br/>
<div class="total"><div>
```

**EDIT** with one button selectable at a time:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var baseAmount = 0;
  var totalAmount = baseAmount;
  $('.button__form').on('click', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
      $(this).removeClass('selected');
      totalAmount = parseInt(totalAmount) - parseInt(value);
    }
    else {
      $('.button__form').removeClass('selected'); // remove selected css from all the other buttons
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      totalAmount = baseAmount; // reset the totalAmount to the original base amount
      totalAmount = parseInt(totalAmount) + parseInt(value);
    }    
    $('.total').html(totalAmount);
  });
});
```

```css
.selected {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button__form" value=10>10</button>
<button class="button__form" value=25>25</button>
<button class="button__form" value=50>50</button>
<button class="button__form" value=100>100</button>
<button class="button__form" value=250>250</button>
<button class="button__form" value=500>500</button>
<br/><br/>
<div class="total"><div>
```

Comment: It works, however, it's adding and subtracting multiple times on button click when I only want to it to add and subtract the value of the button once. Any suggestions?

Comment: so once you select and deselect that same button, it can never be added again? (as in if you click all the buttons 2 times each, you will end up with a total value of 0?)

Comment: I've changed your snippet a little for my needs, but basically the only thing I need to fix is that  I'm able to select more than one button at once, which I do not want to do. I've updated my snippet in the original post.

Comment: so youre saying that only 1 button can be selected at any given time. if i select 10 then 50, 10 will automatically deselect and the total value will show 50 (not 60)?

Comment: Exactly. One button selected at a time. So, if your `current value = 0`, selecting the button for $10 should make your total value `current amount` + `button's value`, which would be $10. But if you then hit the $50 button, the previous button should be deselected and the button's value subtract from the total, leaving you with a new total of $50.